# "Volevo leggere" o "vorrei leggere"?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

Il mio dubbio riguarda la correttezza dell'uso dell'imperfetto in un contesto in cui stai parlando con un amico di cosa farai il venerdì sera e gli dici:

- Volevo leggere un libro che mi hanno prestato

È corretto questo uso dell'imperfetto? Essendo un'azione che poi si compie nel futuro, sarebbe più corretto "voglio leggere" o "vorrei leggere"? Oppure l'imperfetto dà una sfumatura di "ho pensato di leggere" e quindi esprime il concetto di una pianificazione avvenuta nel passato?

Comment: Uso abitualmente questa forma nel linguaggio parlato, e con la stessa sfumatura che le attribuisci tu: mi trovo spesso a dire "mah, domani volevo andare al cinema, tu che fai, ci vieni?" ed è una scorciatoia per "ho pensato di". Non so se sia un colloquialismo, e lo eviterei nel linguaggio scritto, ma è anche vero che il linguaggio scritto presenta poche occasioni per usare questa forma e si trovano piuttosto casi apparenti come "volevo andare al cinema, ma ho cambiato idea", che non c'entrano nulla con la tua domanda (se ho capito bene, il punto è proprio che manca un "ma").

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @Elena!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Direi che sia un uso molto simile a quello che Serianni, nel suo *Italiano* (XI, 374), chiama “imperfetto di modestia” o “d'intenzione”, spiegando:

> Non indica un'azione di tempo passato, ma si adopera per esprimere «un desiderio con un tono garbato di apparente rinuncia: ‘*volevo* la tal cosa’, ‘*cercavo* di te’, ‘*venivo* per parlarti’ invece che ‘*voglio*, *cerco*, *vengo*’: quasi che il soggetto volesse dire ‘volevo questo, ma, se non è possibile, non importa, ne fo a meno’ e simili» (Ronconi). Forse più che di «imperfetto di modestia» sarebbe preferibile parlare di «imperfetto d'intenzione»: infatti questo tempo verbale può essere adoperato non solo per presentare in forma attenuata una richiesta o un'affermazione, ma anche per disporsi all'ascolto (così, entrando in un negozio, il commesso può rivolgercisi con un «Desiderava?» oltre che con l'usuale «Desidera?»). In sostanza, si tratta di una modalità che può confrontarsi con altri costrutti con valore «attenuato», quali l'indicativo e il condizionale di cortesia ... e che può essere accostata all'imperfetto conativo. Ecco un esempio di Cassola (*La ragazza di Bube*, 32-33): «– Be' parla allora –. – Prima di tutto *volevo* dirti che vado a stabilirmi a San Donato».

L'imperfetto conativo menzionato è quello di frasi come «Per poco non mi ammazzavo».

<sub>Poi – osservazione personalissima – anch'io in certe circostanze lo trovo curioso, come quando qualche studente mi scriveva: «Le volevo chiedere [la tal cosa]» e mi veniva da pensare «E adesso? Non me la vuoi chiedere più?»</sub>

Comment: Molto interessante, grazie.

Comment: Il costrutto analogo a quello con il verbo volere si usa anche in spagnolo. Per esempio, il/la commesso/a di un negozio può chiedere "¿Qué quería?", domanda a cui si può rispondere, per esempio, con "Quería un kilo de patatas".

Comment: Un interessante [articolo al riguardo](http://www.maldura.unipd.it/GeD/DOCS/2-2009/05santipolo-qpl.pdf).